# Clear Internet Explorer cache SOTI script

Tags: batch-file, internet-explorer, cmd, windows-embedded, soti

is there any option how to clear IE cache with script set in SOTI mobicontrol?
Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 Classic

I think it can be something like batch file, but there are some system files that cannot be deleted

Cache, temp. files and other junk is in these folders:
\Windows\Profiles\guest\Temporary Internet Files*.*
\Windows\Profiles\guest\Cookies*.*
\Windows\profiles\guest\History\History.IE5

This is how to clear junk files [from GUI](https://honeywellaidc.force.com/supportppr/s/article/How-to-clear-Internet-Explorer-Mobile-cached-cookies-history-temp-files)

We have more than 200 PDA and it take a while to clear cache on all devices one by one.

Thanks

Comment: This script shows using rundll32.exe to clear cache items. https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Clear-Internet-Explorer-5ee32ff6

Comment: that not working on win embedded